# Binary data from marklogic rest endpoint

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, marklogic, binary-data

I have marklogic rest endpoint which is returning huge amount of data. As of now I am using String to get that data but is there any way to get it in binary format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MarkLogic should be sending the data with an appropriate content-type header, so you should be able to consume it with any appropriate reader.

Guessing you are speaking about Spring RestTemplate, I think this is more a Spring question than a MarkLogic one. The following blog post seems to indicate you can use HttpMessageConverters to hook up readers for other formats:

https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/038-retrieve-file-spring-resttemplate/

It roughly seems to come down to:

```
public RestTemplate() {
    this.messageConverters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
    //...
}
```

and

```
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
messageConverters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(messageConverters);
```

and

```
public void fetchFile() throws IOException {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(
            new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

    ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            "https://www.google.com/assets/images/srpr/logo11w.png",
            HttpMethod.GET, entity, byte[].class, "1");

    if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
        // Do something with it..
    }
}
```

(untested, just copied from the blog to here for posterity)

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the MarkLogic Client Java API to make the request, you can use one of the classes implementing the BinaryReadHandle interface to access the response including

- BytesHandle to get the binary in memory
- InputStreamHandle to get the binary as an input stream
- FileHandle to write the binary directly to a file

For more information about those classes, follow the links from BinaryReadHandle:

http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/io/marker/BinaryReadHandle.html

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Thank you but I am using marklogic rest endpoint so I am consuming it using rest template.

Comment: What REST template are you using?  To clarify, the MarkLogic Client Java API executes requests on the MarkLogic REST API.

Comment: Agree that "Client Java API executes requests on the MarkLogic REST API" on top of that we can directly expose custom REST endpoint from Marklogic.